# htaccess: rewrite /directory/file.php to execute /file.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have probably a rather simple mod_rewrite question, however I didn't know how what to google for and how to do this in the best way.

In my php/html code I have regular links linking to `/directory/file.php`

However the `/directory/` doesn't actually exist, and the `file.php` lies in the root of the server. I just want the url to make more sense if I add `/directory/` to it.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^directory/(.+?\.php)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

This will internally route a request of `/directory/abcd.php` to `/abcd.php`.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible that in this case the paths inside the file.php are no longer valid? E.g. stylesheets are not loaded properly, etc.

Comment: That is due to your use of relative links in css/js paths. To fix that issue try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.